# Bittorrent is unchosen how to choose it as default software for torrent download?

Tags: default-programs, bittorrent

In Ubuntu 12.04, how can I choose Transmission as the default bittorrent client? Somehow I unchose it.

Comment: I tried to edit your post so it was more clear what was being asked. I hope my edit was not too invasive.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide:

http://www.howtogeek.com/117709/how-to-change-your-default-applications-on-ubuntu-4-ways/

Is quite easy to do it just from a torrent file you already downloaded.